# How to prove the series $ \sum_{n} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n} + (-1)^n} $ diverge.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Prove that the series of the general terms:
> $$ u_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}  \text{ and } v_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n} + (-1)^n} $$
> do not converge even if we have $ u_n / v_n \rightarrow 1 $

---

We have $ \sum u_n $ converges, I need to show that $ \sum v_n $ diverges, splitting $ \sum v_n $ into $ \sum v_{2n} + \sum v_{2n + 1} $

I found that both series diverge which is not helpful. Is there another way?

Comment: if$ \sum v_{2n} + \sum v_{2n + 1}$, both the series diverge that simply implies that $\sum v_n $diverges too. And also$ u_n / v_n \rightarrow 0$, not $1$.

Comment: @SarthakSahoo No, the sum of two series that diverge is not necessarily a series that diverge. $\sum \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n}$ converges, but both $ \sum \frac{1}{n}$ and $\sum \frac{1}{n + 1}$ diverge.

Comment: yeah my bad misread the question forgot one of them was negative, hence its $\infty-\infty$ and that doesn't necessarily tend to $\infty$.